Unexpected behavior of 'some' PSI CPU metric
I am trying to understand the meaning of the "some" row of the Linux PSI metric for CPU.  The Linux documentation (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/accounting/psi.rst) writes:

The "some" line indicates the share of time in which at least some tasks are stalled on a given resource

My interpretation of this is that any time for which even a single task is runnable but is denied CPU, counts towards the "some" metric.
However, I am observing something different. I have a 4 core machine (cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep -c processor is 4).  And I have the following program:
#include <unistd.h>

#ifndef NUM_PROCS
#define NUM_PROCS 5
#endif

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PROCS - 1; ++i) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
      break;
    }
  }

  while(1);
  return 0;
}

With 5 total tasks (NUM_PROCS=5) contending for 4 cores, I expected the "some" metric to be close to 100% all the time (there should always be a runnable task waiting for an idle CPU).  Instead, I observe the following:
$ cat /proc/pressure/cpu
some avg10=25.76 avg60=23.20 avg300=14.56 total=106289779
full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0

In addition, the "some" percent grows with the number of blocked tasks.  With NUM_PROCS=7 (3 tasks blocked instead of 1), I see the following:
$ cat /proc/pressure/cpu
some avg10=73.99 avg60=67.53 avg300=36.53 total=217437650
full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=0

Which is roughly 3x the NUM_PROCS=5 case.
I'm not in a containerized environment, so as expected, "full" is zero.
Can anyone help me understand what is PSI CPU reports?  It seems to be a percent of CPU time, instead of real time (I expected real time).  But if that were the case, I would expect the percent to be allowed to go above 100, but that also doesn't seem to be the case (when NUM_PROCS is set to a big number "some" PSI is close to 100).

I think I've found the answer to my question in this article https://lwn.net/Articles/753840/.  In particular:

What to make of this number? If CPU utilization is at 100% and CPU
pressure is 0, it means the system is perfectly utilized, with one
runnable thread per CPU and nobody waiting. At two or more runnable
tasks per CPU, the system is 100% overcommitted and the pressure
average will indicate as much. From a utilization perspective this is
a great state of course: no CPU cycles are being wasted, even when 50%
of the threads were to go idle (and most workloads do vary). From the
perspective of the individual job it's not great, however, and they
might do better with more resources. Depending on what your priority
is, an elevated "some" number may or may not require action.


Another great explanation is here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/sched/psi.c#L67.
